# Mikrotik routeros maximum number of filter rules

Tags: firewall, routing, mikrotik, routeros

We need to deploy a service using Mikrotik routerboard CCR. We need to know how many filter/mangle rules a Mikrotik device can support: hundreds, thousands ?
What about performance, cpu and memory usage ? Could someone report real production or test cases ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using about 45 filter rules and 50 mangle rules with a RB433UAH, on a small network with about 20 users. CPU hovers at around 10-20%. This is not a very powerful routerboard, but it seems to handle the rules very well regardless.

Layer 7 protocol filtering is obviously more CPU intense.

I believe on slightly more powerful routerboard/RouterOS hardware, you won't have problems with several hundred filter/mangle rules. 1000's may be pushing the limits